# How to set ToolBar into PreferenceScreen in android

Tags: android, xml

I want use `PreferenceScreen` for my application setting, but i want show this **Preferences** below the **`ToollBar`**.
**toolbar.xml code :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="Setting Page"
    />
```

**setting_preferences.xml (path is : res/xml) code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="setting_title_title_category"
        android:title="Title options">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:id="@+id/setting_title_show_id"
        android:key="setting_title_show"
        android:title="Show Main Title"
        android:summary="Show/hide MainPage title"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="setting_title_text"
        android:title="Set Main Title"
        android:summary="Change MainPage title"
        android:dialogTitle="Change Title"
        android:dialogMessage="Change title please..."/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="setting_title_font_category"
        android:title="Font options">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="setting_title_font_color"
            android:title="Title font colors"
            android:summary="Change title font colors"
            android:entries="@array/colors"
            android:entryValues="@array/colors"
            android:dialogTitle="Change font color" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**SettingPage code :**

```
public class SettingPage extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("setting_title_font_color")) {
            // get preference by key
            Preference pref = findPreference(key);
            // do your stuff here
        }

        if (key.equals("setting_title_show")){

            Preference pref = findPreference(key);
        }
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting_prefrences);
        }
    }
```

How can it? show setting_preferences.xml beloe ToolBar .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a normal `Activity` / `AppCompatActivity` with a simple layout that contains the `Toolbar`. Then in the content area of the `Activity` layout, use a `PreferenceFragment` to show the `PreferenceScreen`.

Comment: I want use this method : `Preference pref = findPreference(key);` , and in Activity/AppCompatActivity dose not use this method. i should use this `PreferenceActivity`

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am asking you to use `PreferenceFragment` instead of `PreferenceActivity`. `PreferenceFragment` has the `findPreference` method you want to use.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

Comment: thanks you my dear friend. can you send me code. please ?

Comment: You can search Internet for freely available examples of `PreferenceFragment`. For example, a quick search yielded this link - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment